# jQuery show only divs matching multiple checkbox parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a system to filter through some tags by hiding and showing the appropriate items.

When .brandFilter is clicked, it needs to show the div using the id of the checkbox. When .prodFilter is clicked, it needs to show the corresponding colors but not show any deselected ID's (unless none have been selected, in which case show everything matching the color).

Right now when I click Epson and HP it works; but when I click Red it will show the red Lexmark product which is not desired; it was already filtered out when I selected the brand. Ideally clicking #brnd_HP, #brnd_Epson and #typ_Red will display Product A and F.

Deselecting a filter should "undo" whatever previous work it did.

Below is the markup I have now:

```
<h2>Brand</h2>
    <input type="checkbox" class="brandFilter" name="brandFilter" id="brnd_Canon" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="brandFilter" name="brandFilter" id="brnd_Epson" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="brandFilter" name="brandFilter" id="brnd_HP" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="brandFilter" name="brandFilter" id="brnd_Lexmark" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="brandFilter" name="brandFilter" id="brnd_Xerox" />

<h2>Color</h2>
    <input type="checkbox"  class="prodFilter" name="typeFilter" id="typ_Red" />
    <input type="checkbox"  class="prodFilter" name="typeFilter" id="typ_Blue" />

<div class="prdbx brnd_Epson typ_Red">Product A</div>
<div class="prdbx brnd_Canon typ_Red">Product B</div>
<div class="prdbx brnd_Epson typ_Blue">Product C</div>
<div class="prdbx brnd_Lexmark typ_Red">Product D</div>
<div class="prdbx brnd_Canon typ_Blue">Product E</div>
<div class="prdbx brnd_HP typ_Red">Product F</div>
```

The jQuery is not functioning as intended, but this is what I have so far. I really can't seem to wrap my head around the seemingly query like nature of toggling visibility with multiple parameters like this. The HP/Epson part works fine, but once the color is introduced it simply shows everything relating to the color ID.

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        $('.brandFilter').click(function(e) {
            $('.brandbx').hide();
            var thisFilter = "";
            $('input[name=brandFilter]:checked').each(function(e) {
                thisFilter += '.'+this.id;
            });
            $(thisFilter).show();
        });

        // when a filter is clicked
        $('.prodFilter').click(function(e) {
            $('.prdbx').hide(); // hide all products
            var thisFilter = "";
            var thisCounter = 0;
            // for each clicked filter
            $('.prodFilter:checked').each(function(e) {
                thisFilter += '.'+this.id;
                $('.'+this.id).show(); // show the products matching filter
                thisCounter++;
            });
            if(thisCounter == 0){
                $('.prdbx').show(); // if no clicked filters, show all products
                $('.brandbx').show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the filters which means persisting the filter from the first checkbox somehow. This works.

```
 var thisFilter1 = "";
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        $('.brandFilter').click(function(e) {
            $('.brandbx').hide();
            thisFilter1 = "";
            var sep = ""
            $('input[name=brandFilter]:checked').each(function(e) {
                thisFilter1 = thisFilter1 + sep + '.'+this.id;
                sep = ","
            });
            $(thisFilter1).show();
        });

        // when a filter is clicked
        $('.prodFilter').click(function(e) {
            $('.prdbx').hide(); // hide all products

            var thisCounter = 0;
            var thisFilter = "";
            var sep=""
            // for each clicked filter
            $('.prodFilter:checked').each(function(e) {
                thisFilter = thisFilter + sep + '.' + this.id;
                sep=","
                thisCounter++;
            });
            if(thisCounter == 0){
                $('.prdbx').show(); // if no clicked filters, show all products
                $('.brandbx').show();
            }
            else {
                $('.prdbx').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).is(thisFilter1) && $(this).is(thisFilter)){
                        $(this).show()
                    }
                })
            }           

        });
    });
```

EDIT: Updated for multiple selection combos. Say hello to jquery .is(). An interesting function that does not return a jq object so can't be chained but can be used inside an if test. You can now have Canon red, blue or red + blue, or HP + Canon blue, etc.

Comment: Hmm, when I select 2 brands, I get no products. I imagine this is because no single div has both brand classes; am I misunderstanding or mistaken? The color/brand filter seems to work just fine now though.

Comment: `if(thisCounter == 0){
                $('.prdbx').each(function() {
                 if ($(this).is(thisFilter1)){
                  $(this).show()
                 }
                });
                $('.brandbx').show();
            }
`
I believe this to be a useful modification; I believe in your original post, checking a brand, then filter, then unchecking the filter would show all products; not just the ones previously selected in the brand selection

Comment: Another suggestion: if thisFilter1 is not set, the if check will always hide the product when thisFilter is engaged. I changed the code slightly to this:                 `if(thisFilter1 != ''){
                     if ($(this).is(thisFilter1) && $(this).is(thisFilter)){$(this).show()}else{$(this).hide()}
                    }else{
                     if ($(this).is(thisFilter)){$(this).show()}else{$(this).hide()}
                    }`

Answer (score 0):

I might have not understand the desired functionality because in my code none of the products is shown at the beginning.

HTML:

```
<h2>Brand</h2>
<input type="checkbox" class="brandFilter" name="brandFilter" id="brnd_Canon" /> Canon
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="brandFilter" name="brandFilter" id="brnd_Epson" /> Epson
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="brandFilter" name="brandFilter" id="brnd_HP" /> HP
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="brandFilter" name="brandFilter" id="brnd_Lexmark" /> Lexmark
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="brandFilter" name="brandFilter" id="brnd_Xerox" /> Xerox
<br />

<h2>Color</h2>
<input type="checkbox" class="prodFilter" name="typeFilter" id="typ_Red" /> Red
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="prodFilter" name="typeFilter" id="typ_Blue" /> Blue

<div class="prdbx brnd_Epson typ_Red show">Epson Red</div>
<div class="prdbx brnd_Canon typ_Red show">Canon Red</div>
<div class="prdbx brnd_Epson typ_Blue show">Epson Blue</div>
<div class="prdbx brnd_Lexmark typ_Red show">Lexmark Red</div>
<div class="prdbx brnd_Canon typ_Blue show">Canon Blue</div>
<div class="prdbx brnd_HP typ_Red show">HP Red</div>
```

CSS:

```
.prdbx {
  display: none;
}

.prdbx.show {
  display: block;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(".brandFilter").on('change', function() {
  //Filter by brand first
    filterByBrand();

    //Then filter by color
    filterByProd();
  });

  $(".prodFilter").on('change', function() {
    filterByProd();
  });
});

function filterByBrand() {
  var $allBrands = $(".brandFilter");

  if (!$allBrands.filter(':checked').length) {
    //If all brand checkboxes are unchecked, show all prdbx divs
    $('.prdbx').addClass('show');
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < $allBrands.length; ++i) {
      var $brand = $allBrands.eq(i);

      //If a brand is checked show it, otherwise hide it
      if ($brand.is(':checked')) {
        $('.' + $brand.attr('id')).addClass('show');
      } else {
        $('.' + $brand.attr('id')).removeClass('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

function filterByProd() {
  var $allProdFilters = $(".prodFilter");
  var noneIsSelected = true;

  for (var i = 0; i < $allProdFilters.length; ++i) {
    var $prodFilter = $allProdFilters.eq(i);
    var $prod = $('.' + $prodFilter.attr('id'));

    //If the checkbox is checked
    if ($prodFilter.is(':checked')) {
      noneIsSelected = false;

      if (!$prod.hasClass('show')) {
        $prod.addClass('show');
      }
    } else {
       $prod.removeClass('show');
    }
  }

  //If no color is selected, filter by brand
  if (noneIsSelected) {
    filterByBrand();
  }
}
```

And here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mehmetb/m2zLt6Lo/

Comment: This seems to be filtering properly except as you mentioned, the products are hidden at the beginning.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now it shows all products at the beginning.

Comment: It seems to break if there is more than one style of ID. Please take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ugbxL47/ do you have any ideas or suggestions on how to get that to work? I believe as it navigates the DOM, it shows the item, then recognizes an unclicked filter below it and hides it again.

Comment: Yes, since it only shows prods with a class name matching the checkbox id